# Why does ArrayList have "implements List"?

Tags: java, collections

In the Collection Framework we have the interface `List` and the class `AbstractList`:

```
AbstractList implements List
```

And `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList` and

```
implements List
```

My question: why does `ArrayList` have the `implements List` clause?

If `ArrayList extends AbstractList` and `AbstractList implements List`, can't we say, that `ArrayList implement List`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes. It could've been omitted. But thus it is immediately visible that it is a `List`. Otherwise an extra click through the code / documentation would be required. I think that's the reason - clarity.

And to add what Joeri Hendrickx commented - it is for the purpose of showing that `ArrayList` implements `List`. `AbstractList` in the whole picture is just for convenience and to reduce code duplication between `List` implementations.

Comment: Not only that, but I prefer this style because it is intention-revealing.  The goal of arraylist is to implement List.  Extending abstractlist is just a way of achieving that goal.

Comment: @Joeri Hendrickx agreed. +1 for the comment

Comment: If the base class implements an interface, the current JavaDoc tool (both Oracle's and the Gnu version) will list that the derived class implements the interface automatically, without your putting `implements TheInterface` on the derived class. So no extra clicks required. (This is true even if the base class is not public.)

Answer (score 8):

My 2 cents is to keep to the fact that ArrayList **is a** List. AbstractList just completes certain implementations that the List requires.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely this is to increase tracability of the inheritance structure. That way you don't have to go down the whole inheritance tree, when browsing the Javadoc or the like.