# Implementing Super and sub interfaces both in a class(class A implements SuperInterface, SubInterface)

Tags: java, interface

```
interface A {

    public void doSomething();
}

interface B extends A {

    public void doSomethingElse();
}

public class AClass implements A, B {

    public void doSomething() {}

    public void doSomethingElse() {}

}
```

Why does Java permit such a declaration? What's the use of implementing both interfaces when same thing can be achieved by implementing the SubInterface (B)?

Comment: What would be gained by not allowing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would both a parent and child class implement the same interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668429/why-would-both-a-parent-and-child-class-implement-the-same-interface)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the "why" question can only be answered by Java designers.

One reason might be that it permits retrofitting `extends A` to `B` without breaking any existing classes that already happen to implement both.

Another reason for using this construct might be to make it immediately clear to the end user of `AClass` that the class implements both `A` and `B`. This is discussed in [Redundant implementation of List interface in ArrayList.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973900/redundant-implementation-of-list-interface-in-arraylist-java/13973997#13973997)

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a convenience. It can be difficult to track what the interface structure is, and would be onerous on a programmer to have to track it all down. Besides, no good can come from not permitting redundant interfaces: implementing an interface multiple times may be unavoidable. For example:

```
interface A { ... }
interface B extends A { ... }
interface C extends A { ... }
public class AClass implements B, C { ... }
```

In this case, A is "implemented" twice, but that's no problem. It simply means that `AClass` must implement each method declared in `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Answer (score 2):

Had this been an error, adding a base interface to an existing public interface would have been a breaking change.
(in case client code has a class that already implements both interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

1) Why not implementing A twice is redundant but leads to no confusion.

2) interface `B` may be changed (and may no longer extending `A`). 
   `AClass`would still implement `A` and `B`

Answer (score 0):

Redundant inheritance declarations have an effect on certain reflection calls.

```
interface One {}
interface Two extends One {}
static class Three implements Two {}
static class Four implements One, Two {}

public static void main(String... args) {
    Three three = new Three();
    Four four = new Four();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(three.getClass().getInterfaces()));  // [Two]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(four.getClass().getInterfaces()));  // [One, Two]
}
```

This probably isn't a reason to design your classes in a certain way, but demonstrates that it does have an effect at runtime.