# combination of extend abstract class and implement interface

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does ArrayList have “implements List”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387419/why-does-arraylist-have-implements-list)

I have gone through several articles [Diff b/w I vs AC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo) and questions on SO about when to use an interface vs Abstract Class.

When I stumbled upon ArrayList Class, ArrayList class extends AbstractList Class implements List interface. AbstractList and List has common methods like add(), remove() etc.

**Edit:** In other words, if AbstractList implements List why have Arraylist class implement List

When is this kind of combination inheritance behavior design preferred when both have common methods?

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>
```

Comment: *"AbstractList and List has common methods like add(), remove() etc."* => AbstractList does implement List: `public abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E>`

Comment: AbstactList also implements List ..

Comment: In other words, `implements List` in the ArrayList declaration [is redundant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387419/why-does-arraylist-have-implements-list).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometime I create an abstract `BaseClass` which implements an interface `IBaseClass` and create `ChildClass` which extends the `BaseClass`. What I mean is:

```
public interface IBaseClass {

}

public abstract class BaseClass implements IBaseClass {

}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

}
```

Now Say I have an interface `IChildClass` and `ChildClass` implements it.

```
public class ChildClass extends BaseClass implements IChildClass {

}
```

And say the `IBaseClass` has a method `someMethod`. Now if you want to use the instance of `ChildClass` by the implementing interface `IChildClass` like:

```
IChildClass obj = new ChildClass();
```

Then you cannot call `obj.someMethod()`. Then you need to do this:

```
public interface IChildClass extends IBaseClass {

}
```

You can find in [Java 1.2 documentation](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.2-docs/api/index.html) the the interface `java.util.List` doesn't extends `java.util.Collection`, which it does in the latest version. `java.util.List` was the supreme interface at that time and `java.util.AbstractList` implements that `List` also the `ArrayList`. `AbstructList` in turns extends the `AbstractCollection`. `AbstractCollection` was then supreme class. Currently `AbstractCollection` implements `Collection`. So it is clear that this design pattern has been followed to keep the Java's ever expandable pattern in mind.

Answer (score 3):

The `implements List` is redundant in this case. It is possibly to make it clear this call implements List without have to navigate the class hierarchy.

Comment: Hmm.. Just for readability?

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractList<E>` also implements `List<E>`, so they are the same methods.