# Is there any benefit in implementing a interface in a subclass even though the superclass implements the same interface

Tags: java, oop

When I was seeing the declaration of `ArrayList`

```
class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

which implements `List` interface even though `ArrayList`'s superclass `AbstractList` implements the same `List` interface.

```
abstract class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E>
```

Similar declarations can be found on `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap` declarations also.

[image]

In the declaration of `LinkedHashMap`, it implements `Map` interface only and not the other interfaces implemented by its superclass `HashMap`.

So there might be some benefits of having such declarations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no functional benefits to declaring them again, it does not affect the behavior in any way.

I guess it's only added to make it clearer which interfaces are implemented.

Comment: If making clearer is the only benefit, then LinkedHashMap may even implement Cloneable, Serializable interfaces. But it has not.

Comment: @CharlesGreenWay I would typically write `Map<..> map = new LinkedHashMap<>()`, but rarely `Cloneable cloneable = new LinkedHashMap<>()`... a `LinkedHashMap` is mainly a `Map`, although it implements other interfaces as well.

Comment: Thanks @Heuster for explaining. Will this be also for compatibility (i.e) If in future, HashMap doesnot implement Map(even though this might not happen), then LinkedHashMap may still implement Map

Answer (score 3):

This is done for documentation purposes only, to make it immediately clear to the user of the class which interfaces the class implements.

The redundant `implements` clause makes no difference to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It could've been omitted. But thus it is immediately visible that it is a List. Otherwise an extra click through the code / documentation would be required. I think that's the reason - clarity.

And to add what Joeri Hendrickx commented - it is for the purpose of showing that ArrayList implements List. AbstractList in the whole picture is just for convenience and to reduce code duplication between List implementations.

Reference: [Why does ArrayList have "implements List"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387419/why-does-arraylist-have-implements-list)

Answer (score 1):

Totally unnecessary. I wouldn't do it at all.

It's unclear why they did that by then. But by now apparently it's a mistake, since everybody is surprised by it when they first notice this odd redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this way you must implement `List<E>` methods when you create a subclass to `AbstractList`, and you can also use an `ArrayList` as an `AbstractList`.

Comment: Question is why `ArrayList` explicitly implements `List`, even though it implicitly does this by extending `AbstractList` already. Which is for clarity only, as pointed out by Keppil and NPE.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<T>` and `AbstractList<T>` implement `List<T>` for different purposes.

- `List<T>` *establishes* what is required for a class to be a list.
- `ArrayList<T>` implements `List<T>` as part of defining its own *interface*. This is essential to what `ArrayList<T>` is.
- `ArrayList<T>` extends `AbstractList<T>` as part of its own *implementation*. This is entirely optional: one could have implemented `ArrayList<T>` from scratch without inheriting `AbstractList<T>`, and the class would work in the same way.
- `AbstractList<T>` is intended as a base class for other implementations of `List<T>`. Instead of *establishing* an interface, it *follows* an existing one. `AbstractList<T>`'s implementation of `List<T>` is not required, everything would compile and run without it just the same. However, inheriting `List<T>` lets Java compiler spot potential discrepancies between the interface methods and the methods of `AbstractList<T>`, so it is a very good idea for `AbstractList<T>` to implement `List<T>` interface.