# Why LinkedList implements List interface again in java

Tags: java, list, linked-list

Why does `LinkedList` implement the `List` interface in java even though it extends `AbstractList` which implements `List` interface already?

Comment: Your question should probably be generalized. Something like *"Why would you implement an interface in a class whose parent already implemented it?"*, then give the lists as an example. Because this probably happens a lot, not just regarding lists.

Comment: Probably very similar: [Why does arraylist class implement List as well as extend AbstractList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558536/why-does-arraylist-class-implement-list-as-well-as-extend-abstractlist)

Comment: @Gendarme makes sense.

Comment: @JornVernee Looks same, thanks for pointing.