# Is it right to use extend and implement in the same class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism, implementation, extends

```java
interface A {
    void someMethod();
}

class B implements A {
    void someMethod() {
        //do something
    }
}

class C extends B implements A {
    void someMethod() {
        super.someMethod();
        //do something
    }
}
```

I'm using the above design in one of my codes. It is working fine. **My whole purpose here is to use the default implementation of class B and do something extra in class C.** Is this the correct way to use the implementation? Is there any better design patter to be looked at?

Because If I define my class C as below, still everything works fine. But this neglects the whole purpose of using implementation (to force class C to implement methods of interface A).

```java
class C extends B implements A {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to both extend and implement on the same classes.
in fact, if you'll look at `HashMap` (and many others), that's exactly what it does:

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable
```

Comment: It might be worth linking to the question explaining why the collections framework does both, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558536/why-does-arraylist-class-implement-list-as-well-as-extend-abstractlist

Answer (score 0):

It still works fine because when you extend B that comes along with an implementation of someMethod, thus fulfilling the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand that
`class C extends B implements A` is exactly equal to `class C extends B` other than the quick documentation purpose.

Try removing the defination of `someMethod()` from `class C` and see if your code compiles or not. It will compile. The reason is, the moment you made `C` extend `B`, `C` by default gets all the methods defined in `B` which includes an impementation of `someMethod()` as well. Defying the whole purpose of your explicit contract.

If you really want to force `C` to give a defination of `someMethod()` then try the following code:

```java
interface A {
    void someMethod();
}

abstract class B implements A {
    protected void someUtilMethod() {
        //do common/default defination
    }
}

class C extends B {
    void someMethod() {
        someUtilMethod();
        //do extra something
    }
}
```